# Removing words from large textfiles using lexicon

Tags: java, mysql, nlp, text-processing

I have +8 million textfiles containing +500 words each. I need to process them in order for me to do Keyword extraction and Tag prediction to automatically tag such files.

When reading papers around this topic, I found a paper where they use, during their preprocessing phase, a custom lexicon. This lexicon is used to filter out noisy elements such as misspellings or arbitrary variable names in embedded code segments.

Now since I wish to recreate their methods and - hopefully - improve by adding my own contribution, I was wondering what the most efficient way is to process my data using such lexicon. Due to the large amount of data, I want a solution that is fast (in correlation with the large amount) and memory efficient.

However I am stuck thinking how to implement this. Is the fastest, most efficient way just to do brute-force querying of each word in every textfile and if that word is not in the database, remove it from the file? (Which would take long and require a lot of computations/memory IMHO). **Or** is there a faster way such that I can query the database with the complete textfile (or as a string) making the database perform such preprocessing (so taking every word, looking up if in lexicon and remove if not so, then later return the shorter textfile/string)?

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. Are you trying to tag files based on the keywords present in these files? From your question, I get the feeling that the lexicon is used only to filter out noisy elements. Does the lexicon play any greater role in this whole process?

Comment: Yes it will be mainly used to filter out noisy elements. I need to get clear words which are part of the lexicon in order for me to train a classifier that can make such tag assignment automatically for future files.

Comment: Are these plain text files? If so, then getting clear words is simply a matter of tokenizing properly. If not, can you include a short example (like a snippet from a file) in the question?